# How to Resolve/Change "Needs investigation" status in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

"Needs investigation" message show in firebase analytics dashboard. How to change the status on firebase.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on Needs investigation  --> It will open a page where it will show details of that specific release and towards the end you will be seeing something like below

[image]

Click on View crash details. It will show all the crash reports which you have to fix. and release a build.

Comment: There is no crash in iOS, still it shows the "Needs investigation" message.

Comment: Just click on that it will give you all the details. For ios You have to upload your dSYM files for more details go through this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios